# Creating ipad version from iphone version?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I've developed an iPhone app. I want to make the same application version of iPad. What you need to change the version of iPhone? What do I need for iPad version? Do I just change my UI design or are there any places in the code have to change?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the device in the summary (Project in proejct navigator -> App under Targets -> Summary -> Device -> iPad/iPhone/Universal). You can check which device the app is running on with this code. Then you can load different xib files and adjust your views for the specific device.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
} else
{
   viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

choose your project file in project navigator, then choose your target -> summary -> iOS Application target -> make sure it is iPad camatible. Then only design left...

Comment: Sentinel, Do I need larger one that I use images for iPad version? I added @2x for all images is that enough?

Comment: @2x is fo retina display. You may laft all images like for iphone, but your app will only at pare of creen. iPad screen size is 1024x768. You just need to make images equal to this size.

Answer (score 0):

Select the target and further go in bundle settings

go to deployment tab and then select the "iPad" in "targeted Device family"

then convert all Xibs with the ipad resolution.

Comment: Thank you Balla well, Xibs seems iPhone size, not iPad, how can I change it?